# How to plot geographical coordinates in mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, maps, mapbasic

I want to get started with mapinfo and plot some coordinates i.e latitude and longitute
. How is it possibe?

Comment: Read MapInfo help...that's the best place to start.

Comment: How are you wanting to create data? Are you wanting to click on a map to place points? Or do you have a spreadsheet or text file with coordinates in it already?

Comment: Reading mapinfo help is gud thought but i am reading a lot but it's a lot of reading to do since i also need to learn mapbasic and read this or that is not kind of helpful

Comment: I agree, your question is quite unclear.
If you want to see the coordinates from your mapinfo file plotted you can simply use Qgis and upload mif/tab file as a vector.
If you want to create a mapinfo file from scratch, ujjwalesri already suggested you read help or definition first. It is quite simple format and you can create it even with notepad if you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **Mapping Wizard Tool** to load in your text file of latitude and longitude coordinates. Just set the correct datum (usually World WGS84) to overlay them correctly.

[image: MI Professional screenshot]

Guide to using the Mapping Wizard Tool:
http://www.oocities.org/mapinfotutorial/wizard.html

Comment: +1 It's nice to see a clear example of MapInfo use.